# Using DirectShow library to edit and save an mp3 file

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, directshow

I want to read an mp3 file, crop section of it, fade in & out and finally save it as a new mp3 file. I found a library called DirectShow that apparently can do this, but I can figure out how to do it. Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) (Sound eXchange):

> SoX is a cross-platform (Windows,
>   Linux, MacOS X, etc.) command line
>   utility that can convert various
>   formats of computer audio files in to
>   other formats. It can also apply
>   various effects to these sound files,
>   and, as an added bonus, SoX can play
>   and record audio files on most
>   platforms.

I recommend that you have a look at the [features](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features) page. It seems to offer exactly what you need to do.

> Multiple audio files can be combined
>   (and then further processed with
>   effects) using any one of the
>   following combiner methods:
>
> - concatenate
> - mix
> - merge: E.g. two mono files to one stereo file
> - sequence: For playing multiple audio files/streams

Now using this you can simply use the command line file in conjunction with `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process.Start()` and you should be on your way. A very quick example:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(PathOfCmdLine);
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Arguments = "ArgsHere";

Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: This looks even more promising than the one above

Comment: I also used ffmpeg. This works too. It's less of a hassle to to get working but SOX has much more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can look a library called WinnydowsMediaLib available on http://www.winnydows.com/#Downloads website. It's a .net wrapper for ffmpeg library. FFMpeg is able to open, cut and save mp3 files

Comment: looks promising, will check it out. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with the open-source .NET lib NAudio: http://naudio.codeplex.com